How do I upload an image via CKEditor version 4 in this Laravel 8 app?
I have been working on a blogging application in Laravel 8.
I use CKEditor 4 in the form tasked with adding a new article.
I web.php I have added this route:
Route::post('/ckupload', [ArticleController::class, 'ckupload'])->name('dashboard.articles.ckupload');

The form view:
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('dashboard.articles.add') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    @csrf
    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Title') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('title') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="Title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" name="title" value="{{ old('title') }}" autocomplete="title" autofocus>

                    @error('title')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
            <label for="short_description" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Short description') }}</label>

            <div class="col-md-12 @error('short_description') has-error @enderror">
                    <input id="short_description" type="text" placeholder="Short description" class="form-control @error('short_description') is-invalid @enderror" name="short_description" value="{{ old('short_description') }}" autocomplete="short_description" autofocus>

                    @error('short_description')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                            </span>
                    @enderror
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="category" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Category') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('category_id') has-error @enderror">

            <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror">
                <option value="0">Pick a category</option>
                @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>


                @error('category_id')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center switch-toggle">
                <p class="mb-0 me-3">Featured article?</p>
                <input class="mt-1" type="checkbox" id="featured" name="featured" {{ old('featured') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                <label class="px-1" for="featured">{{ __('Toggle') }}</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="image" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Article image') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 post-image @error('image') has-error @enderror">
            <input type="file" value="{{ old('image') }}" name="image" id="file" class="file-upload-btn">

            @error('image')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label for="content" class="col-md-12">{{ __('Content') }}</label>

        <div class="col-md-12 @error('content') has-error @enderror">

            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Content" cols="30" rows="6">{{ old('content') }}</textarea>

            @error('content')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @enderror
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mb-0">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Save') }}
                    </button>
            </div>
    </div>
</form>

In the controller, I have:
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\ArticleCategory;
use App\Models\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    
  private $rules = [
        'category_id' => 'required|exists:article_categories,id',
        'title' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'short_description' => 'required|string|max:190',
        'image' =>  'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',
        'content' => 'required|string'
    ];

    private $messages = [
        'category_id.required' => 'Please pick a category for the article',
        'title.required' => 'Please provide a title for the article',
        'short_description.required' => 'The article needs a short description',
        'short_description.max' => 'The short description field is too long',
        'content.required' => 'Please add content'
    ];

    public function ckupload(Request $request) {
      if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
        $fileName = md5(time()) . Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('images/articles'), $fileName);
        $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
        $url = asset('images/articles' . $fileName);
        $response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url')</script>";
        @header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        echo $response;
      }

      return false;
    }

    public function save(Request $request) {
        // Validate form (with custom messages)
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        $fields = $validator->validated();

        // Upload article image

        if (isset($request->image)) {
            $imageName = md5(time()) . Auth::user()->id . '.' . $request->image->extension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('images/articles'), $imageName);
        }

        // If no image is uploaded, use default.jpg
        $fields['image'] = null == $request->image ? 'default.jpg' : $imageName;

       // Upload image via CKEDITOR
       $this->ckupload($request);

        // Turn the 'featured' field value into a tiny integer
        $fields['featured'] = $request->get('featured') == 'on' ? 1 : 0;

        // Data to be added
        $form_data = [
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
            'category_id' => $fields['category_id'],
            'title' => $fields['title'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($fields['title'], '-'),
            'short_description' => $fields['short_description'],
            'content' => $fields['content'],
            'featured' => $fields['featured'],
            'image' => $fields['image']
        ];

        // Insert data in the 'articles' table
        $query = Article::create($form_data);

        if ($query) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard.articles')->with('success', 'The article titled "' . $form_data['title'] . '" was added');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Adding article failed');
        }
    }
}

I call CKEditor like this:
<script>
   CKEDITOR.replace('content', {
      filebrowserUploadUrl: '{{route('dashboard.articles.ckupload').'?_token='.csrf_token()}}',
      filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form'
    });

    CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
      event.editor.on("beforeCommandExec", function(event) {
          // Show the paste dialog for the paste buttons and right-click paste
          if (event.data.name == "paste") {
              event.editor._.forcePasteDialog = true;
          }
      })
    });
</script>

The problem
When trying to upload an image via CKEditor, I get this error in the browser console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

When I use the "Upload" tab of the editor's dialog (see image below), I get the error

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)


Questions

What causes the described error?
What is the most reliable way to fix the issue (besides upgrading CKEditor to version 5)?


I have fixed the issue by changing the ckupload method to:
public function ckupload(Request $request)
  {
      if ($request->hasFile('upload')) {
        $originName = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileName = pathinfo($originName, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('upload')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = md5(time()) . Auth::user()->id . '.' . $extension;
        $path = public_path('images/articles');
        $fileName = $request->file('upload')->move($path, $fileName)->getFilename();

        $CKEditorFuncNum = $request->input('CKEditorFuncNum');
        $url = asset('images/articles/' . $fileName);
        $response = "<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($CKEditorFuncNum, '$url')</script>";

        echo $response;
      }

      return false;
}

There is no need to call this method within the save() method.
